# Failures when signing a 64-bit driver using Windows Logo Kit

Tags: windows, driver, signing, driver-signing

Currently I am working on signing a 64-bit driver for a USB tool which is used to scan areas of the skin.

My setup is like this:

- DTM Controller and DTM Studio are
  running on a Server machine (Windows
  Server 2003 R2 SP2)
- DTM Client running on a Client Machine (Windows 7 64-bit)

I have managed to run tests on the client, using DTM Studio, but I get a couple of errors and I´m not sure why but I have some ideas.

The failures I encounter are the following:

**Run INFTest against a single INF**

1. RunJob – Copy of CHKINF and INFTest Library Job
2. Could not find user specified INF files. Bailing out...
3. Could not expand user supplied list of infs into individual filenames.

**Sleep Stress With IO**

1. RunJob – Sleep_Stress_With_IO .
2. Device has issues and not ready for test. Device Problem Code is: 28

**Disable Enable With IO**

1. RunJob – Disable_Enable_With_IO
2. Device has issues and not ready for test. Device Problem Code is: 28

**Common Scenario Stress With IO**

4. Execute_Device_Status_Check_Script
5. Device has issues and not ready for test. Device Problem Code is: 28

When I located the INF file in DTM Studio and added the tests I received the error: „No devices using the specified driver“. This is off course correct as the machine running the DTM Client (Windows 7 64-bit) does not have the driver installed for the USB tool.

So my question is:

**Do i need to install the driver for the USB tool on the client machine?**

If that is needed then the client machine must run a different version of Windows which brings to me my next question:

**Can I run Logo tests successfully for a Windows 7 64-bit OS when the Client (running DTM Client) is set up using a different OS?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to answer my questions:

**Do I need to i install the driver for the USB tool on the client machine?**

Yes this is needed.

**Can I run Logo tests successfully for a Windows 7 64-bit OS when the Client (running DTM Client) is set up using a different OS?**

No. The client machine must be set up using the target OS.